# Nexus 4 does not seem to boot. What options are there?

Tags: nexus-4, unbricking

I had not used my nexus 4 for a long time. Took it out recently charged it up and when attempting to boot, it just does not start. Some times it turns off at "Optimizing apps" screen and sometimes it won't even go past Google logo.

Tried to boot into recovery mode with power and volume button but no luck. It just shuts down after Google Logo.

Could you please let me know if I could wipe it clean and flash it ?

Comment: Try getting into fastboot mode via the other volume/power combo. If that works, flash a factory image.

Comment: Nexus 4's are the biggest troll phones ever. I had one, used to think it's a good phone until it decided that it won't work anymore for no reason. It's like it has a built in expiration date after 2  years, my friends reported similar issues where one's screen acted erratically like the phone was possessed. Ever since, I've had an samsung s4 that I'm still using today for 4 years with custom roms and still fast. Do yourself a favour and just throw it in the trash and never look back and don't ever buy a nexus or google phone.